# ASCII and 64bit Registers Assembly

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, ascii, cpu-registers

When I give 1 as the input of this code from keyboard, rbx is changed to a31h. But the ASCII value of the number '1' is 30h. So why rbx became a30h?

```
section .text

global _start

_start:

mov rax,1
mov rdi,1
mov rsi,msg
mov rdx,len
syscall

mov rax,0
mov rdi,0
mov rsi,num
mov rdx,1024
syscall

mov rbx,[num]

mov rax,60
mov rdi,0
syscall

section .data

msg: db 0Ah,"Enter here:",0
len: equ $ - msg

section .bss

num: resb 10
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you've specified 1024 as the length which means the `read` syscall is getting *two* bytes, the `31h` representing the character `'1'`, and the `0ah` representing the newline.

If you only want one character, only ask for one character, not 1024.

And, if you try to get the full width into `rbx`, ensure you clear out the upper bits afterwards, something like:

```
mov rbx, [num]
and rbx, 0ffh
```

Although a better solution is probably just to load up a byte with zero extension:

```
movzx rbx, byte [num]
```

Comment: Since you provided a code sample, you might want to mention `movzx` too, so people won't mistakenly think the `and` method is the best.

Comment: @Jester, thanks, it was just a warning on how OP had done it, I wasn't thinking too hard about the _best_ way. But, per your advice, I've added it.

Comment: Got the idea. Thank you both for the help.